Best architecture for a react microfrontend project that uses kafka pub sub?
Lets say you have a MFE react project that is composed of 3 MFE components... Now say you want to have a pub sub system in place so that any component can publish/subscribe to any topic and if any of the other MFE components care can subscribe to...
The solution I've sort of come up with is as follows...
Each MFE component communicates via websocket to its own server (something like socket.io) which then in turn communicates with a backend say .net core which communicates with apache kafka...
Does this make any sense or am I way overcomplicated this architecture? In my example of one page having 3 MFE components does this mean I would have 3 separate websocket connections per user? Is there a way to simplify this while still having the mfe components being loosely coupled?

Sounds complicated. What is the purpose / design goal of all those in-between servers? Why isn't a single websocket-kafka proxy thing enough? There are also apparently message passing techniques like events (window.dispatchEvent(e)) that work in browser and allow decoupled components to talk to e.g. a central backend communication component which could then keep just 1 connection for any amount of components (via https://sharvishi9118.medium.com/cross-micro-frontend-communication-techniques-a10fedc11c59)

I 100% could be overthinking it and if I only wanted communication between MFs on a given page then window.dispatcheven would 100% be the solution (I think there are limitations to using that on mobile though). To explain all the servers (in my head once again 100% I'm probably wrong).. MF -> unique Socketio server -> backend -> kafka. Unique socketio server is so each of the mfe are independent and don't have to be linked together. Backend for any of the buisness logic and to call kafka... kafka for all the pub sub logic
